# Google Maps API: mouse wheel zoom breaks on Chrome if scrolled quickly

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I've encountered this with Chrome on maps using the Javascript API. I **don't** see this bug (a) on the regular Google Maps page or (b) using Safari.

I can replicate this on Google's basic demo page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

The problem occurs whenever I spin the mouse wheel quickly. At that point,  the mouse wheel zoom stops working (mostly).

- Zooming by clicking on the +/- buttons still works fine.
- On the demo page above, if you spin the mouse wheel without holding the alt or ⌘ key, it will show a message like "Use ⌘ + scroll to zoom the map". This still appears, so the map doesn't appear to be losing the mouse wheel event itself. (The problem is not limited to maps that require holding down a key, though.)
- The mouse wheel zoom also doesn't stop working entirely, it just looks like it's dropping 90% (or more) of the events. If I spin the mouse wheel quickly, the map will usually respond (but will zoom an unpredictable number of levels). If I spin the wheel one tick at a time, eventually one of the ticks will trigger a zoom.
- No error or diagnostic messages appear in the console.

Comment: Try logging the `deltaY` of the wheel event, and see if it behaves differently with the mouse or trackpad.

Comment: I can't reproduce the described problem in Chrome [Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)] on Windows 7.